# PHP difference in days between two date strings

Tags: php, datetime

I have these two strings:

```
20/3/2020
30/3/2020
```

And I want to get the difference in days between them so I use this code:

```
$dateS = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/M/Y", "20/3/2020");
$dateE = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/M/Y", "30/3/2020");

echo $dateE->diff($dateS)->days;
```

But I always get a crash with this code

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function diff() on bool

Any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You can see the error using `print_r(DateTime::getLastErrors())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date format string is incorrect. `M` is a format parameter meaning

> A short textual representation of a month, three letters ex. Jan through Dec

If your months will not have a leading zero you need to use `n`:

```
<?php
$dateS = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/n/Y", "20/3/2020");
$dateE = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/n/Y", "30/3/2020");

echo $dateE->diff($dateS)->days;
```

Output:

```
10
```

See [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for what each format parameter represents.